# Android Studio - Change image when in different state

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imagebutton

I want to have a favorite button on my app like in Gmail

[image]

So, when the user click on the star, the star became yellow, and when the user clicked it again, it turn back to normal

How can i make this happen with my custom image?
i have two images

when its not favorited (heart-grey.png)
and when its favorited (heart-red.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use visibilty to do this.You have to define the xml to have both images at the same postion(It can be done using Relative layout).

```
    final ImageView play = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play);
    final ImageView play2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play2);

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Drawable playImage = play.getDrawable();
            if (playImage.isVisible()){
                play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                play2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mediaPlayer.start(); }

            }

    });

    play2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Drawable playImage2 = play2.getDrawable();
            if (playImage2.isVisible()){
                play2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your star is an ImageButton you can do something like this :

```
   starSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 //add a condition to detect if it is already a favorite or not
             if(starSelected.getDrawable() == R.drawable.theimage2) {
                starSelected.setImageResource(R.drawable.thenewimage);
             }else{
                starSelected.setImageResource(R.drawable.thenewimage2);
             }

        }
    });
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In your java code create a boolean flag:

```
boolean isSelected = false
```

Set an onClickListener inside your onCreate for the star (ImageView, Button whatever it is). Inside onClick, check for the flag like this:

```
if (isSelected) {
    // change image src to unselected
    isSelected = false;
} else {
    // change image src to selected
    isSelected = true;
}
```

and also you can save the boolean state with SharedPreferences to make sure you get the correct state every time.